# Could not find x-ref table PDF

Tags: pdf

I'm trying to load a PDF file so I can extract it as an image. I've tried a couple of packages in Python e.g. PyPDF2, but each time I encounter the message "Could not find xref table at specified location".

I don't have any experience with PDFs and Python, so any tips would be appreciated. An example file is given here:

https://beta.companieshouse.gov.uk/company/00002404/filing-history

where the PDF is the 'full accounts' link.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The PDF in question is broken: The offset of the cross reference table and most object offsets in it are completely wrong.

E.g. the PDF claims that the cross reference table starts at file position 24732 but it actually starts at position 1594356. And the cross reference table entry for object 208 claims it to be at position 24713 while it actually is at 1594337.

Thus the observed error message *"Could not find xref table at specified location"* is completely correct.

The first offsets in the table are correct, though, at first glance up to the first image stream.

It appears as if the software producing the PDF did not count image stream contents when determining object offsets. Or it took a template with very small placeholder images and replaced the image streams of these small images by much larger streams without updating cross reference offsets.

Comment: Thank you for taking a look. Is there any workaround for me here? I just want to convert it to an image to extract text.

Comment: Open the PDF in Adobe Reader. When you close it again, Adobe Reader asks you whether it should save it. The saved copy is repaired. (It may be, though, that Adobe Reader saves the file making use of features available in PDF 1.5; there still are some tools and libraries out there which cannot handle those features.) Alternatively you can copy the images from Adobe Reader into a graphics program of your choice.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the advice :) Would you happen to know if there would be a nice way to automate this? I could be working with thousands of similar files.

Comment: Contact the providers of that web page. After all the site is marked a "trial service" and asks for feedback and also has a link "Is there anything wrong with this page?" at its bottom. If you want to repair the files yourself, some PDF libraries have repair features. I would assume iText (for Java and .Net) can repair the file; I haven't tried, though.

Comment: Thanks again - you've been a great help.

Comment: Seems like a very tedious task, tried repairing with ghostscript with no success. Your workaround is good, but I'm in Linux and Adobe isn't supported anymore (as far as I know)

Answer (score 7):

You can use [QPDF](http://qpdf.sourceforge.net/) for this since it has a faulty xref table recovery method.

Just run `qpdf broken.pdf repaired.pdf` where `broken.pdf` is the broken input PDF and `repaired.pdf` is the new file name.

I tried it with the PDF you linked to and it worked fine.

Comment: Awesome - just what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Works really nice. Thanks!

Comment: Or try pikepdf if you want to keep all of it in python. It is a PDF library based on QPDF so it handles broken PDFs fine

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by gettalong, you could use qpdf to fix a corrupted PDF. Nowadays you can also simply use **[pikepdf](/questions/tagged/pikepdf)** (which is based on qpdf) instead of PyPDF2. That library is able to work well with corrupted PDFs because it is based on qpdf.

Example:

```
import pikepdf
pdf = pikepdf.Pdf.open(file)
```

Pikepdf docs: https://pikepdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: pikedpdf for the win

Comment: When I import pikepdf, I receive the following error. Why is that and what can be done to resolve it? 

TypeError: __new__() missing 8 required positional arguments: 'accessibility', 'extract', 'modify_annotation', 'modify_assembly', 'modify_form', 'modify_other', 'print_lowres', and 'print_highres'